# Compute RDF between COMs of two selections (or groups) using GROMACS

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs, radial-distribution-function

I have been using `gromacs` since years but I am always confused when I want to perform the following task: compute the RDF (radial distribution function) between the COMs (center of masses) of two selections or groups.

I am assuming I can define selections within the command line via `-sel` and `-ref-` options, however I am always confused if to include `com` there or in the `-selrpos` option.

**Example:**
I have several residues and I want to compute the RDF between the COMs of the selection made by atoms C1 C2 C3 (in all residues). Possible syntax:

```
1$ gmx rdf -f ftraj.xtc -s ftraj.tpr -ref "com of name C1 C2 C3" -sel "com of name C1 C2 C3" -selrpos res_com 
2$ gmx rdf -f ftraj.xtc -s ftraj.tpr -ref "com of name C1 C2 C3" -sel "com of name C1 C2 C3"
3$ gmx rdf -f ftraj.xtc -s ftraj.tpr -ref "name C1 C2 C3" -sel "name C1 C2 C3" -selrpos res_com 
4$ gmx rdf -f ftraj.xtc -s ftraj.tpr -ref "name C1 C2 C3" -sel "name C1 C2 C3" -selrpos res_com -seltype res_com
5$ gmx rdf -f ftraj.xtc -s ftraj.tpr -ref "name C1 C2 C3" -sel "name C1 C2 C3" -selrpos whole_res_com -seltype whole_res_com
```

`1$` and `2$` return zero everywhere, while `3$` peaks at atomic positions (not COMs). It seems only last commands (`4$` or `5$`) are doing somehow what I am looking for but I am not sure what is the difference (and there is difference). So, further confusion is due to the option listed for `selrpos`: what would be the difference between res_com, whole_res_com, part_res_com and dyn_res_com?
Also, the option `seltype` is only documented in last versions of `gmx rdf`.

Besides, I am assuming I could pre-define "C1 C2 C3" as a group via `gmx make_ndx`

Any clarification is welcome :)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I can offer a bounty to help get it solved.

Comment: I have found a solution, yes.  I'll post it asap!

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax is then the following:

```
$gmx rdf -f ftraj.xtc -s ftraj.tpr -ref "name C1 C2 C3" -sel "name C1 C2 C3" -selrpos part_res_com -seltype part_res_com
```

My thoughts were partially clarified after consulting the useful command `gmx help selections positions` where it is described that `POSTYPE can be atom, res_com, res_cog, mol_com or mol_cog, with an optional prefix whole_ part_ or dyn_`:

- `whole_` calculates the centers for the whole residue/molecule, even if only part of it is selected
- `part_` prefix calculates the centers for the selected atoms, but uses always the same atoms for the same residue/molecule
- `dyn_` calculates the centers strictly only for the selected atoms.

However, I still want to test the default behaviour (which should be `part_` when selections are provided, and `whole_` otherwise).